# Who should be owed to the Morita equivalence theorem on modules over algebras?

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $k$-algebra, then we know there exists a quiver Q with an admissible ideal $J$ such that $$\operatorname{mod} A\cong\operatorname{mod} kQ/J$$
I was wondering who discovered this fact. Is it C.M.Ringel or someone else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(First, note that this is only true for all $k$-algebras if $k$ is algebraically closed.)

I believe that it is (essentially, at least) due to P. Gabriel. At least, the quiver $Q$ is often called the "Gabriel quiver" of $A$.

I don't know any publication of his that gives this precise statement, but I think that the essential ideas are (in a much more general context) contained in the last few sections of

*Gabriel, Peter*, Indecomposable representations. II, Sympos. math. 11, Algebra commut., Geometria, Convegni 1971/1972, 81-104 (1973). [ZBL0276.16001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0276.16001).